# JSON Encoding from Dictionary [ Cannot invoke 'dataWithJSONObject ...]

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, swift2

I have a dictionary :

```
    var schedule : [String:[(Bool,Bool)]]!//[Day:[(AMenabled:PMenabled)]]
```

and I want to decoded it to a json file to put it to the server

the schedule object is like this :

```
        ["Sat":[ (true,true),
             (false,true),
             (false,false),
             (false,true),
             (false,false),
             (false,true),
             (false,false),
             (false,true),
             (false,false),
             (false,true),
             (false,false),
             (true,true)
        ],
        "Sun":[ (true,true),
            (false,true),
            (true,true),
            (false,true),
            (true,true),
            (false,true),
            (true,true),
            (false,true),
            (true,true),
            (false,true),
            (true,true),
            (false,true)
        ],
        "Mon":[ (true,true),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (true,false),
            (true,true)

        ],
        "Tue":[ (true,true),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),

            (false,true)
        ],
        "Wed":[ (true,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,true),
            (true,true),
            (true,true)
        ],
        "Thur":[ (true,true),
            (false,true),
            (true,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false)
        ],
        "Fri":[ (true,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,false),
            (false,true),
            (false,true),
            (true,true),
            (true,false)
        ]
    ]
```

and I want to decoded to something like this JSON file:

```
{
"parental_control": {
    "user_id": 57,
    "profile": 1,
    "chat": false,
    "forum_read": false,
    "forum_write": false,
    "days": [
        [
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true
        ],
        [
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true
        ],
        [
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true
        ],
        [
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true
        ],
        [
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true
        ],
        [
            true,
            false,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            false,
            true
        ],
        [
            true,
            false,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            true,
            false,
            true
        ]
    ]
}
}
```

So without taking care of the parentalcontrol and other keys in the json file , How to achieve the mapping to json file :

**What I have tried ?**

I have tried using the builtin `NSJSONSerialization`

```
var json = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self.schedule, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted,error: nil)
```

but I am getting this error:

> cannot invoke dataWithJSONObject with an argument list of type
>   '([String:[(Bool,Bool)]]!,options:NSJSONWritingOptions,error:nil)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get is because `NSJSONSerialization` is having trouble to serialize your `(Bool, Bool)` tuples (tuples are not available in JSON). Your will have to convert them to an appropriate type in order to serialize them.

Also, here is the first paragraph of [`NSJSONSerialization` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html). You can use this as a reference for valid types (Note that Swift's respective types like Strings, Arrays, Dictionaries etc will of course work as expected):

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
> properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or
>   NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your example and it uses an Array instead of tuples. Because `NSJSONSerialization` can't handle tuples since there are no such things in JSON.

```
var days = ["Mon", [true, false]]

let json = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(days, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)
let _days = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as! Array<AnyObject>

println(_days[0]) // prints Mon
println(_days[1][0]) // prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSJSONSerialization` does not include tuples so you can define `schedule` as:

```
var schedule : [String:[Array<Bool>]]!
```

Insert Data in `schedule`:

```
schedule =  ["Sat":[ [true,true],
      [false,true],
      [false,false],
      [false,true],
      [false,false]
      ],
      "Sun":[ [true,true],
        [false,true],
        [true,true],
        [false,true],
        [true,true],
        [false,true]
      ]]
```

Now you can cast it into JSON data:

```
var jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self.schedule, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted,error: nil)
```